# Identify code-pieces one specific person mainly worked on

Tags: gratis, git

a co-worker leaves and I would like to identify parts of the code that might need explanation / handover.

I'm looking for [gratis](/questions/tagged/gratis) software that helps me to identify parts of the code in a git-repository on which mainly one person has worked.

I imagine something like a `git blame`. But where `git blame` just shows me for the HEAD and a given file who edited the lines, I would like to see for a given user all files where the user has made a lot of changes (not necessarily only in the HEAD, but that would be a start).

The simplest way I could imagine would be to make `git blame` on all files and print the files in descending order by the number of lines that user has changed in the given file, so something like:

```
$ find-git-contributions --main-contributions john.doe@example.com 
123 lines: main.py
 70 lines: Dockerfile
  2 lines: requirements.txt

$ find-git-contributions --main-contributor john.doe@example.com 
100%: Dockerfile
  5%: main.py
  1%: requirements.txt
```

If this could automatically group by folder it would be even better.